# Dplyr join on by=(a = b), where a and b are variables containing strings?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to perform an inner join two tables using dplyr, and I think I'm getting tripped up by non-standard evaluation rules. When using the by=("a" = "b") argument, everything works as expected when "a" and "b" are actual strings. Here's a toy example that works:

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

inner_join(iris, iris, by=c("Sepal.Length" = "Sepal.Width"))
```

But let's say I was putting inner_join in a function:

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

myfn <- function(xname, yname) {
    data(iris)
    inner_join(iris, iris, by=c(xname = yname))
}

myfn("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
```

This returns the following error:

`Error: cannot join on columns 'xname' x 'Sepal.Width': index out of bounds`

I suspect there is some fancy expression, deparsing, quoting, or unquoting that I could do to make this work, but I'm a bit murky on those details.

Comment: Hadley calls this ["non-standard evaluation"](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) (NSE)

Comment: Seems not so much NSE as delivering the "by.x" and "by.y" column names in a different manner. The `by`-argument becomes `c("Sepal.Length" = "Sepal.Width")` and so what would be the `by.x` argument to `merge` becomes a real R name. In fact it's almost the opposite of NSE as I view it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use

```
myfn <- function(xname, yname) {
    data(iris)
    inner_join(iris, iris, by=setNames(yname, xname))
}
```

The suggested syntax in the `?inner_join` documentation of

```
by = c("a"="b")   # same as by = c(a="b")
```

is slightly misleading because both those values aren't proper character values. You're actually created a named character vector. To dynamically set the values to the left of the equals sign is different from those on the right. You can use `setNames()` to set the names of the vector dynamically.

Comment: Note that by using `setNames`, the order of the arguments is inverted with respect to the original use in `inner_join`. To have the same order of the arguments, i.e. first `xname` then `yname`, you could use `by=setNames(nm=xname, yname)`.

Comment: Isn't there any way to include the `!!xname, !!yname` syntax here? In other dplyr verbs like rename you can access the values of character objects by using the two exclamation marks before the object.

Comment: @AlbertoAgudoDominguez the development version of dplyr has a `join_by` function that will allow you to use !! but as of now that is not part of the official dplyr release as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

I like MrFlick's answer and fber's addendum, but I prefer `structure`. For me `setNames` feels as something at the end of a pipe, not as an on-the-fly constructor. On another note, both `setNames` and `structure` enable the use of variables in the function call.

```
myfn <- function(xnames, ynames) {
  data(iris)
  inner_join(iris, iris, by = structure(names = xnames, .Data = ynames))
}

x <- "Sepal.Length"

myfn(x, "Sepal.Width")
```

A named vector argument would run into problems here:

```
myfn <- function(byvars) {
  data(iris)
  inner_join(iris, iris, by = byvars)
}

x <- "Sepal.Length"

myfn(c(x = "Sepal.Width"))
```

You could solve that, though, by using `setNames` or `structure` in the function call.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party, but how about:

```
myfn <- function(byvar) {
  data(iris)
  inner_join(iris, iris, by=byvar)
}
```

This way you can do what you want with:

```
myfn(c("Sepal.Length"="Sepal.Width"))
```

Comment: I don't that as substantially different than the MrFlick answer.

Comment: They are very similar. The only difference is when you are joining by multiple dimensions. I think it's clearer to do `myfn(c("a" = "b", "c" = "d"))` than `myfn(c("a", "c"), c("b", "d"))`, but it's a matter of taste I guess.

Comment: Yeah. I can see your point. You are using redundant quotes though. You could call yours with `myfn(c(a = "b", c = "d"))`, and to my eyes that would be even clearer since it use the usual entry of the names, not to mention fewer characters that need a shift-key.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a nearly identical challenge as @Peter, but needed to pass multiple different sets of `by =` join parameters at one time. I chose to use the `map()` function from the tidyverse package, `purrr`.

This is the subset of the tidyverse that I used.

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
```

First, I adapted `myfn` to use `map()` for the case posted by Peter. 42's comment and Felipe Gerard's answer made it clear that the `by` argument can take a named vector. `map()` requires a list over which to iterate.

```
    myfn_2 <- function(xname, yname) {
      by_names <- list(setNames(nm = xname, yname ))

      data(iris)

      # map() returns a single-element list. We index to retrieve dataframe.

      map( .x = by_names, 
           .f = ~inner_join(x = iris, 
                            y = iris, 
                            by = .x)) %>% 
        `[[`(1)
    }

myfn_2("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
```

I found that I didn't need `quo_name()` / `!!` in building the function.

Then, I adapted the function to take a list of `by` parameters. For each `by_i` in `by_grps`, we could extend `x` and `y` to add named values on which to join.

```
by_grps <- list(  by_1 = list(x = c("Sepal.Length"), y = c("Sepal.Width")), 
                  by_2 = list(x = c("Sepal.Width"), y = c("Petal.Width"))
                )

myfn_3 <- function(by_grps_list, nm_dataset) {
  by_named_vectors_list <- lapply(by_grps_list, 
                                  function(by_grp) setNames(object = by_grp$y,
                                                            nm = by_grp$x))
  map(.x = by_named_vectors_list, 
      .f = ~inner_join(nm_dataset, nm_dataset, by = .x))
}

myfn_3(by_grps, iris)
```