# full_join by variable as column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr's `full_join` to combine two data.frames, for example:

```
col1 = 'b'
col2 = 'd'

df1 = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3)
df2 = data.frame(a = 1:3, d = 1:3)


full_join(df1, df2, c('a' = 'a', col1 = col2))
```

but it returns

> Error: `by` can't contain join column `col1` which is missing from LHS

I'm looking for an output similar to

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = c('a', col1), by.y = c('a', col2))
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dplyr join on by=(a = b), where a and b are variables containing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399065/dplyr-join-on-by-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-variables-containing-strings)

Comment: What's wrong with `merge()`?

Comment: I think it changes the order, it ruins `geom_polygon` plots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rename_`, i.e.,

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, rename_(df2, .dots = setNames(col2, col1)))
```

which gives,

> ```
> #Joining, by = c("a", "b")
>   a b
> 1 1 1
> 2 2 2
> 3 3 3
> ```

Posting alternatives as per @akrun and @mt1022 comments,

```
#akrun
full_join(df1, rename_at(df2, .vars = col2, funs(paste0(col1))))
full_join(df1, rename(df2, !!(col1) := !!rlang::sym(col2)))

#mt1022
full_join(df1, rename_at(df2, col2, ~col1))
```

Comment: Another option is `rename_at(df2, .vars = col2, funs(paste0(col1)))` or `rename(df2, !!(col1) := !!rlang::sym(col2))`

Comment: @akrun, a less verbose way for the first alternative: `full_join(df1, rename_at(df2, col2, ~col1))`

Comment: @mt1022 THat is very nice

Answer (score 1):

Change the join like this:

```
full_join(df1, df2, by=c('b'='d'))  
a.x b a.y
1   1 1   1
2   2 2   2
3   3 3   3
```

Answer (score 1):

All credits to @MrFlick in the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399065/dplyr-join-on-by-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-variables-containing-strings), slightly modified for `OP`'s example :

```
full_join(df1, df2, by = c("a",setNames(col2, col1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will reproduce your result, is this what you look for though?

```
full_join(df1, df2, by="a")%>%select(-d)
```