# Left join missing left hand side

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to join two dataframes using user selected two columns from a datatable in a shiny app

I'd like to join them using the column names which I have put into a variable. However when I do the left join I get an error. When I use the character of the name it works fine.

**My code**

```
EndoDate<-colnames(RV$data[as.numeric(input$endotable_columns_selected[1])])
EndoNum<-colnames(RV$data[as.numeric(input$endotable_columns_selected[2])])
PathDate<-colnames(RV2$data[as.numeric(input$endotable_columns_selected[1])])
PathNum<-colnames(RV2$data[as.numeric(input$endotable_columns_selected[2])])
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
left_join(RV$data,RV2$data,by = c(EndoDate=PathDate,EndoNum=PathNum))
```

**..But this does work**

```
left_join(RV$data,RV2$data,by = c("endo_resultperformed"="endo_resultperformed","hospitalnumber"="hospitalnumber"))
```

I need to use the column names chosen by the user. How can I do this and do the join?  Is this a symbol dplyr problem?

Comment: Is this of use: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#different-expressions. I cannot try it, as you did not share example data. Also, do you mean datatable or dataframe? If the first, then please add the tag as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
library(dplyr)
band_members$id <- 1:3
band_instruments$id_num <- c(2,3,1)

xid='id'
xid1='name'
yid='id_num'
yid1='plays'

band_members %>% left_join(band_instruments, by=setNames(nm=c(xid,xid1),c(yid,yid1)))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  name  band       id plays 
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <chr> 
1 Mick  Stones      1 NA    
2 John  Beatles     2 guitar
3 Paul  Beatles     3 bass
```

PS: This answer based on @MrFlick answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399065/dplyr-join-on-by-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-variables-containing-strings)