# Join multiple tables dynamically

Tags: r, dataframe, join

### The problem

Hi all,

I am trying to join a few dataframes together dynamically. For me that means that I have a dataframe that I start with `df_A`, to which I want to join multiple other dataframes`df_B1`, `df_B2`,`df_B3`, etc..

`df_A` contains a column for each of the `df_B...` tables to join against. `Column_join_B1`, `Column_join_B2`, `Column_join_B3`, etc. (Although in reality these have obscure names). These names are also in a vector `df_A_join_names`.

`df_B1`, `df_B2`, `df_B3`, etc.. are stored in a list `df_B`, which I understand is good practice to do :). This is also how I access them in my loop.

Each of these has two columns. One with the value to join against `df_A` The other with information.

I even tried renaming the first column to match the column in `df_A` before the join, but to no avail.

### What I am trying

`left_join()` does not allow me simply use `by = c(df_A_join_names[1], "Column_join_A")` so I have to use `setNames`, but I cannot get this to work.

Below a function which I want to iterate in a  loop:

```
my_join <- function(df_a, df_b, a_name, b_name){ 

  df_joined <- left_join(df_a, df_b, 
                            by = setNames(b_name, a_name))
  return(df_joined)
}
```

I want to use this function in a loop to join all my `df_B...` dataframes against `df_A`.

```
for (i in 1: length(df_A_join_names)){

    df_A <- my_join(df_a = df_A,
                    df_b = df_B[i],
                    a_name = as.character(df_A_join_names[i]),
                    b_name = "Column_join_A"
    )
}
```

Running this I get:

```
 Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "list"
```

### Some stuff to play with

```
#Making df_A
A_a <- seq(1,10, by = 1)
Column_join_B1 <- seq(11,20, by = 1)
Column_join_B2 <- seq(21,30, by = 1)
df_A <- data.frame(cbind(A_a, Column_join_B1, Column_join_B2) )

#Making df_B
Column_join_A <- seq(11,20, by = 1)
B_a <- LETTERS[1:10]
df_B1 <- data.frame(Column_join_A, B_a )

Column_join_A <- seq(21,30, by = 1)
B_b <- LETTERS[11:20]
df_B2 <- data.frame(Column_join_A, B_b)

# In my own code I make this using a loop. maybe not the prettiest.
df_B <- list()
df_B[[1]] <- df_B1
df_B[[2]] <- df_B2

df_A_join_names <- c("Column_join_B1", "Column_join_B2")
```

#### References

I'm trying to apply this:

[Dplyr join on by=(a = b), where a and b are variables containing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399065/dplyr-join-on-by-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-variables-containing-strings)

I'm curious to hear what you guys think!

Comment: Do you want to join all datasets in `df_B` into `df_A` to generate one new data? Or join each dataset in `df_B` into `df_A` respectively to get multiple data?

Comment: I was looking to join all datasets in ```df_B``` to ```df_A``` to got one single dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for building a specific function, you can simply use SetNames within left_join function:

```
df_B_join_name <- "Column_join_A"

for (i in 1: length(df_A_join_names)){
  df_A <- left_join(df_A, df_B[[i]], by=c(setNames(nm = df_A_join_names[i], df_B_join_name)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close! The only thing you might need to change is the way you reference the data frame under list df_B. df_B[1] will still be a list, df_B[[1]] will return a data frame. I ran the code below and it worked for me.

```
for (i in 1: length(df_A_join_names)){

  df_A <- my_join(df_a = df_A,
                  df_b = df_B[[i]],
                  a_name = as.character(df_A_join_names[i]),
                  b_name = "Column_join_A"
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, manage to rename the first column in `df_B` to match the column in `df_A`. So `df_B` will look like this:

```
# [[1]]
#    Column_join_B1 B_a
# 1              11   A
# 2              12   B
# .              .    .
# .              .    .
# .              .    .
# 
# [[2]]
#    Column_join_B2 B_b
# 1              21   K
# 2              22   L
# .              .    .
# .              .    .
# .              .    .
```

Next, use `Reduce()` in `base` or `reduce()` in `purrr` to iterate the manipulation of `left_join`. You even don't need to use the for loop.

```
Reduce(left_join, df_B, init = df_A)

#    A_a Column_join_B1 Column_join_B2 B_a B_b
# 1    1             11             21   A   K
# 2    2             12             22   B   L
# 3    3             13             23   C   M
# 4    4             14             24   D   N
# 5    5             15             25   E   O
# 6    6             16             26   F   P
# 7    7             17             27   G   Q
# 8    8             18             28   H   R
# 9    9             19             29   I   S
# 10  10             20             30   J   T
```